# How to move an element of an array to the beginning of the array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to move the element at index 2 to the start of the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the resulting array should look like `[3, 1, 2, 4]`.

My solution was to do the following

`[3] + ([1, 2, 3, 4] - [3])`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: its not rotation, relevant order is changed of values that's not the case of rotation. If you rotate this array by 2 index then you will get - [3,4,1,2].

Comment: It is not rotation.. It's partial rotation, the title says exactly that.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4].values_at(2, 0..1, 3)` would work (and could be further generalized)

Comment: @CarySwoveland If it's not partial rotation, what else should I call it? To me it is similar to [1,2,3,4].rotate(-1) which rotates the entire array clockwise by 1.

Comment: I think the generalization @Stefan is referring to would be `i = 2; [1, 2, 3, 4].values_at(i, 0...i, i+1..) #=> [3, 1, 2, 4]`. This works for all `i`, `0 <= i <= 3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method that takes the first `n` elements from an array and rotates them by one, then adds back the remaining elements.

```
def rotate_first_n_right(arr, n)
  arr[0...n].rotate(-1) + arr[n..-1]
end

rotate_first_n_right([1,2,3,4], 3)
# => [3, 1, 2, 4]
```

This does fail if we try to use it on an array that is too short, as the `arr[n..-1]` slice will yield `nil` which will cause an error when we try to add it to the first array.

We can fix this by expanding both slices into a list.

```
def rotate_first_n_right(arr, n)
  [*arr[0...n].rotate(-1), *arr[n..-1]]
end
```

To see why this works, a very simple example:

```
[*[1, 2, 3], *nil]
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

A problem with you example is what happens if `3` occurs in the array more than once. E.g.

```
[1,2,3,3,3,4] - [3]
# => [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: `ar[0...3] = ar[0...3].rotate(-1)` is also an option.

Comment: Alternatively cap `n` at `arr.length` to avoid `nil`. Or maybe even raise an exception. (what does it even mean to rotate the first 4 items of a 3-element array?)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean about "rotation" as this is not exactly a rotation but you could go with

```
def move_element_to_front(arr, idx)
  # ruby >= 2.6 arr.dup.then {|a| a.unshift(a.delete_at(idx)) } 
  arr = arr.dup
  arr.unshift(arr.delete_at(idx))
end
```

This will move the element at `idx` to the first position in the returned `Array`

Comment: _"this is not exactly a rotation"_ – you could see this as rotating the `arr[0..idx]` subarray (to the left). This is what the OP meant by "partial rotation" as you're not rotating the entire array.

Comment: @Stefan I could see that and would be more inclined to agree if this was a repeated movement e.g. `[3,1,2,4]`, `[2,3,1,4]`, etc. then terminologically speaking I am not sure I could come up with a better explanation of this pattern than partial rotation.

Answer (score 2):

```
def move_element_to_front(arr, idx)
  [arr[idx]].concat(arr[0,idx], arr[idx+1..])
end
```

```
arr = [:dog, :cat, :pig, :hen]
```

```
move_element_to_front(arr, 2)
  #=> [:pig, :dog, :cat, :hen]
move_element_to_front(arr, 0)
  #=> [:dog, :cat, :pig, :hen]
move_element_to_front(arr, 3)
  #=> [:hen, :dog, :cat, :pig]
```

The operative line of the method could alternatively be expressed

```
[arr[idx], *arr[0,idx], *arr[idx+1..]]
```